# find parent('TD') ID loop not displaying entire id

Tags: arrays, loops, element, parent-child

I'm having some issues with getting a parent nodes id to display in entirety.

I'm using a loop to detect div elements within a table, then I'm having it find the parent TD node and in another variable it gets the id off of that.

My problem is that during this loop im building a variable upon itself with this TD id inside an array and when it prints, the first time it will only show the first character, then the second time it will only show the 2nd character and any time after that will come up blank.

if i remove the array from the variable it will print the entire id, but it renames the old values to the most recent each time the loop runs.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Heres the function im writting

```
test.save = function () {

var cell = rd = REDIPS.drag,
    page1a = document.getElementById(redips.p1a),
    divs = TableID.getElementsByTagName('DIV'),
    rd.find_parent('TD', rd.obj),     //parent cell
    st = cell.id,                           //parent cell ID
    st,                     
    id,                                     //div id
    cid,                                   //cell id    
    ccid, 
    concatenator,                         // concatenate oDiv ID
    query = '',
    div,                                // current DIV element
    i;                                  // loop variable

    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {

    // set current DIV element
    div = divs[i];

    // set current TD ID
    cid = st[i];

    if (div.className.indexOf('drag') > -1) {

                    //takes two characters off of the DIV ID only
        concatenator = div.id.substring(0, div.id.length - 2);

        // creates the query through the loop
            query += cid + '=' + concatenator + ' ';
        }
}

     if (query.length > 0) {
     document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = query;
}
    };
```

heres a link to a version using an array with the TD ID: http://stevenschemers.com/beta1/

and heres a link to a version not using an array for the TD ID: http://stevenschemers.com/beta2/

I also noticed, it seems like the loop if running twice, because 'i' will count up 0, 2, 4, 6. or sometimes 1, 3, 5, 7

Comment: What is `divs`? What is `rd`? What's the structure of the document? What do you mean, remove arrow from the variable?

Comment: Sorry, I ment array. rd relates to a drag and drop function built in ajax. Divs gets the div within the table. The Concatenator variable works perfectly when displaying the div id's in full but not cid

Comment: I updated my code for you to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// loop goes through each DIV element collected on the left side of page 1
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    // set current DIV element
    div = divs[i];

    if (div.className.indexOf('drag') > -1) {
        // sets current cell ID for dropped div
        cid = rd.find_parent('TD', div).id;

        concatenator = div.id.substring(0, div.id.length - 2);
        // creates the query through the loop
            querya += cid + '=' + concatenator + '&';
            qc++;
        }
}
```